# How validate character not allowed in a xml utf-8

Tags: java, xml, validation, character-encoding

I have a xml with utf-8 and it's save in a xmlType in oracle database field. I need to validate that the xml don't contain any character not allowed.
¿How can i do a method for this in java?

Thanks

Comment: Not allowed by what? Please [edit] to give an example and explain why you need to guard against it.

Answer (score 0):

Use  java.lang.String.contains()